# Incorrect padding error in putting SECRET_KEY in .env file

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, secret-key

When I'm using SECRET_KEY value in settings.py, the Django application is working fine but as soon as I put the value in .env file and stating SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY') in settings.py, it is giving padding error.

1. The First case in which I put SECRET_KEY value directly in settings.py is working fine.
2. Second case using .env file giving padding error. Below is the code for the second case.

```
"""
Django settings for swadeshikart project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=True, cast=bool) # True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'category',
    'accounts',
    'store',
    'carts',
    'mathfilters',
    'orders',
    'django_generate_secret_key',
    'admin_honeypot',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
]

SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 3600 # 1 hr
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'swadeshikart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'category.context_processors.menu_links',
                'carts.context_processors.cart_total',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'swadeshikart.wsgi.application'
AUTH_USER_MODEL='accounts.Account'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        'swadeshikart/static',
    ]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'media'

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}

# SMTP configuration
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', cast=int)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', cast=bool)
```

```
SECRET_KEY==m-ddx5p+*hx12n)o1f@g&7lb)10n%50c70$(f3g80-r+8pq73
DEBUG=True
EMAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER=#
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=#
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

```
Error at /
Incorrect padding
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: Error
Exception Value:    
Incorrect padding
Exception Location: /home/rd/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/base64.py, line 87, in b64decode
Python Executable:  /home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart',
 '/home/rd/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/home/rd/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '/home/rd/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 26 May 2021 01:48:21 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 215, in _get_session
            return self._session_cache …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 118, in decode
            return signing.loads(session_data, salt=self.key_salt, serializer=self.serializer) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py, line 135, in loads
    base64d = TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).unsign(s, max_age=max_age).encode() …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py, line 201, in unsign
        result = super().unsign(value) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py, line 184, in unsign
        raise BadSignature('Signature "%s" does not match' % sig) …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception (Signature "k1EFM899XEbldYeSg6kXKkmWENfoSCNnmlP1WUmbmwI" does not match), another exception occurred:
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py, line 113, in __call__
            response = self.process_request(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_session_timeout/middleware.py, line 21, in process_request
        init_time = request.session.setdefault(SESSION_TIMEOUT_KEY, time.time()) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 88, in setdefault
        if key in self._session: …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 220, in _get_session
                self._session_cache = self.load() …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py, line 44, in load
        return self.decode(s.session_data) if s else {} …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 122, in decode
            return self._legacy_decode(session_data) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 126, in _legacy_decode
        encoded_data = base64.b64decode(session_data.encode('ascii')) …
▶ Local vars
/home/rd/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/base64.py, line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s) …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
[unable to retrieve the current user]

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'kNTfdyJGDhD7eUuDWbQqxCn32H6F152mfTDmfTntseXmJ2IRyWfZ0Hsu0Yf0S1Bs'
sessionid   
'x9mgcdqhis7wcbv2c4cf8ms45nynkgro'
META
Variable    Value
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT    
'/home/rd/Android/Sdk'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID   
'********************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY   
'********************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME 
'django-blog-files-rdx'
COLORTERM   
'truecolor'
CONDA_BACKUP_ADDR2LINE  
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-addr2line'
CONDA_BACKUP_AR 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ar'
CONDA_BACKUP_AS 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-as'
CONDA_BACKUP_CC 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc'
CONDA_BACKUP_CFLAGS 
('-march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong '
 '-fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/rd/anaconda3/include')
CONDA_BACKUP_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  
'/home/rd/anaconda3:/home/rd/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr'
CONDA_BACKUP_CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot'
CONDA_BACKUP_CPP    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cpp'
CONDA_BACKUP_CPPFLAGS   
'-DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/rd/anaconda3/include'
CONDA_BACKUP_CXX    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++'
CONDA_BACKUP_CXXFILT    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++filt'
CONDA_BACKUP_CXXFLAGS   
('-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++17 -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona '
 '-mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 '
 '-ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/rd/anaconda3/include')
CONDA_BACKUP_DEBUG_CFLAGS   
('-march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-all '
 '-fno-plt -Og -g -Wall -Wextra -fvar-tracking-assignments -ffunction-sections '
 '-pipe -isystem /home/rd/anaconda3/include')
CONDA_BACKUP_DEBUG_CPPFLAGS 
'-D_DEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Og -isystem /home/rd/anaconda3/include'
CONDA_BACKUP_DEBUG_CXXFLAGS 
('-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++17 -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona '
 '-mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-all -fno-plt -Og -g '
 '-Wall -Wextra -fvar-tracking-assignments -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem '
 '/home/rd/anaconda3/include')
CONDA_BACKUP_ELFEDIT    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-elfedit'
CONDA_BACKUP_GCC    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc'
CONDA_BACKUP_GCC_AR 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc-ar'
CONDA_BACKUP_GCC_NM 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc-nm'
CONDA_BACKUP_GCC_RANLIB 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib'
CONDA_BACKUP_GPROF  
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gprof'
CONDA_BACKUP_GXX    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-g++'
CONDA_BACKUP_HOST   
'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu'
CONDA_BACKUP_LD 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld'
CONDA_BACKUP_LDFLAGS    
('-Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now '
 '-Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/rd/anaconda3/lib '
 '-Wl,-rpath-link,/home/rd/anaconda3/lib -L/home/rd/anaconda3/lib')
CONDA_BACKUP_LD_GOLD    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld.gold'
CONDA_BACKUP_NM 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-nm'
CONDA_BACKUP_OBJCOPY    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objcopy'
CONDA_BACKUP_OBJDUMP    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objdump'
CONDA_BACKUP_RANLIB 
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ranlib'
CONDA_BACKUP_READELF    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-readelf'
CONDA_BACKUP_SIZE   
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-size'
CONDA_BACKUP_STRINGS    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strings'
CONDA_BACKUP_STRIP  
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strip'
CONDA_BACKUP__CONDA_PYTHON_SYSCONFIGDATA_NAME   
'_sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos6_linux_gnu'
CONDA_EXE   
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/conda'
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE    
'/home/rd/anaconda3/bin/python'
CONDA_SHLVL 
'0'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'kNTfdyJGDhD7eUuDWbQqxCn32H6F152mfTDmfTntseXmJ2IRyWfZ0Hsu0Yf0S1Bs'
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    
'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=de537b9439c3d4958854b83560a1125d'
DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS    
'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=de537b9439c3d4958854b83560a1125d'
DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE   
'session'
DEBUG_VALUE 
'True'
DEFAULTS_PATH   
'/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path'
DESKTOP_SESSION 
'ubuntu'
DISPLAY 
':1'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'swadeshikart.settings'
EMAIL_PASS  
'********************'
EMAIL_USER  
'rishabdhyani4@gmail.com'
FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL    
'https://storage.flutter-io.cn'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
GDMSESSION  
'ubuntu'
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID    
'this-is-deprecated'
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE    
'ubuntu'
GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN   
'/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/bccf778d_b127_4117_b15a_2e46273f0f2f'
GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE  
':1.228'
GPG_AGENT_INFO  
'/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
GTK_MODULES 
'gail:atk-bridge'
HOME    
'/home/rd'
HOST    
'x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
('csrftoken=kNTfdyJGDhD7eUuDWbQqxCn32H6F152mfTDmfTntseXmJ2IRyWfZ0Hsu0Yf0S1Bs; '
 'sessionid=x9mgcdqhis7wcbv2c4cf8ms45nynkgro')
HTTP_HOST   
'127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA  
'" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"'
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE   
'?0'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST 
'document'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE 
'navigate'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE 
'none'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER 
'?1'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
 'Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36')
IM_CONFIG_PHASE 
'1'
INVOCATION_ID   
'e40f587fb6e944e8b9d0cc70bde984bf'
JOURNAL_STREAM  
'9:44888'
LANG    
'en_IN'
LANGUAGE    
'en_IN:en'
LESSCLOSE   
'/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
LESSOPEN    
'| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
LOGNAME 
'rd'
LS_COLORS   
'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
MANAGERPID  
'7121'
MANDATORY_PATH  
'/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path'
PATH    
'/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/bin:/home/rd/anaconda3/condabin:/home/rd/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/rd/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/rd/Documents/Development/flutter/bin:/home/rd/.local/bin:/home/rd/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/rd/Documents/Development/flutter/bin:/home/rd/.local/bin'
PATH_INFO   
'/'
PS1 
('(kart) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
 '\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
PUB_HOSTED_URL  
'https://pub.flutter-io.cn'
PWD 
'/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart'
QT_ACCESSIBILITY    
'1'
QT_IM_MODULE    
'ibus'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SERVER_NAME 
'localhost'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSION_MANAGER 
'local/ROG-Strix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/7524,unix/ROG-Strix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/7524'
SHELL   
'/bin/bash'
SHLVL   
'1'
SSH_AGENT_PID   
'7485'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   
'/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
TERM    
'xterm-256color'
TZ  
'UTC'
USER    
'rd'
USERNAME    
'rd'
VIRTUAL_ENV 
'/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart'
VTE_VERSION 
'6003'
WINDOWPATH  
'2'
XAUTHORITY  
'/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS 
'/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
'ubuntu:GNOME'
XDG_DATA_DIRS   
'/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
XDG_MENU_PREFIX 
'gnome-'
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR 
'/run/user/1000'
XDG_SESSION_CLASS   
'user'
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP 
'ubuntu'
XDG_SESSION_TYPE    
'x11'
XMODIFIERS  
'@im=ibus'
_   
'/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/kart/bin/python'
_CE_CONDA   
''
_CE_M   
''
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
<class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>
wsgi.input  
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x7f042b9de650>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module swadeshikart.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'accounts.Account'
BASE_DIR    
PosixPath('/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart')
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': PosixPath('/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER  
'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM   
'sha256'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
'rishabhdhyani4@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT  
587
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
True
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'category',
 'accounts',
 'store',
 'carts',
 'mathfilters',
 'orders',
 'django_generate_secret_key',
 'admin_honeypot']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ar-dz', 'Algerian Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('ig', 'Igbo'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('ky', 'Kyrgyz'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('tg', 'Tajik'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tk', 'Turkmen'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
PosixPath('/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/media')
MEDIA_URL   
'/media/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MESSAGE_TAGS    
{40: 'danger'}
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT  
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'swadeshikart.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY  
'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY  
True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS  
3600
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'swadeshikart.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
['swadeshikart/static']
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
PosixPath('/home/rd/Documents/New_Projects/SwadeshiKart/static')
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                     'category.context_processors.menu_links',
                                     'carts.context_processors.cart_total']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'swadeshikart.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Hi! Please add the code and errors as text, not images.

Comment: Hey, I have added the related code and error.

Comment: Does your key start with equal? If yes, then add it like `SECRET_KEY="=m-ddx5p+*hx12n)o1f@g&7lb)10n%50c70$(f3g80-r+8pq73"`

Comment: @SuyogShimpi Yes, the key starts with equal. Even after adding double inverted commas, it is giving the same error.

Comment: probably should've posted a placeholder instead of the actual _secret_ key...

Comment: @JanWilamowski It is not deployed yet. Obviously, I will change it before deploying the application.

Comment: @RishabhDhyani post the proper traceback instead of that interactive view. Click on the "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and copy the full stack trace and add that to the question.